# Uploading/Download file from and to a Secure Server in Ionic and $cordovaFileTransfer

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an app using Ionic and Cordova, and part of it's functionality is Uploading and Downloading file from a secure location, knowing that such command is working using curl while I put my credentials in **user:pass** way, but in Cordova I'm using the **$cordovaFileTransfer**.

So my question is : how i can add my credentials knowing that authenticating is needed to upload and download files.

and here's my used code :

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

    var url = "https://serverlink/thing.txt";
    var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "/cloud/thing.txt";
    var trustHosts = true;
    var options = {
        params: {
           // Do i put my credentials here ?? 
        }
    };
    console.log('before download');
    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
        .then(function(result) {
            // Success!
            console.log("done downloading the file");
        }, function(err) {
            // Error
            console.log('error yaw !!', err);
        }, function(progress) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
            });
        });

}, false);
```

So, i tested the code above where i put my credentials the params inside the option object,  but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for that, my resource use Basic Authorization, so in order to send any request i need to be authenticated, i managed that by doing the following :

```
authReader = function(username, password) {
                var tok = username + ':' + password;
                var hash = btoa(tok);
                return "Basic " + hash;
};
var options = {
     headers : {
          'Authorization': authHeaderValue('user', 'pass')
     }
}
$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
                .then(function(result) {
                    // Success!
                    console.log("done downloading the file");
                }, function(err) {
                    // Error
                    console.log('error yaw !!', err);
                }, function(progress) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                    });
});
```

By now I set the Header with the Basic Authorization ( hashed in Base64
) and sent the request directly and got back my file from my secure server.

This was basically thr solution for my question.